# Store a dataframe in one cell in postgres

Tags: r, postgresql, store

I have a `data.frame` which contains the grouping logic of region for example:

```
data1 <- data.frame(
    Group = c(1, 2, 3), 
    Region = c("Southeast Med, Southeast Low, Southwest Low, Northeast Med", "Northeast High, East Med, Midwest Med High", "Midwest Low, California and HI, West High"),
    stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want to store this information in one cell in postgres. How can I do it?

I tried converting it into a `list`, but that doesn't work. Other options I am considering is to serialize it. I tried creating it into a vector/string, but I lose the grouping information. I need to post it such that when I extract it, I can re-use it to group the data with the given information.

More details, or flow of thought can be sourced in this question: [R: Creating a new column using another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55286875/r-creating-a-new-column-using-another-dataframe)

Essentially, I am trying to store information from training data, and want to be able to replicate the grouping when new data comes in from the stored information. Happy to provide any more information that is needed, if I missed it.

Comment: *"I want to store this information in one cell in postgres. How can I do it?"* I don't understand your question. What does `data1` and trying to convert it into a `list` have to do with PostgreSQL? Can you add code where you store information in a PostgreSQL database? Are you using `dbplyr` to write to the database?

Comment: I have an existing postgres database, where I have a table, I need to push contents of data1 into one of the columns in that table.

Comment: One method: if the database column is `varchar(...)` with a large-enough size, you can encode your data as json and store it as a string. Postgres supports json natively, so you can go that route too, so this might be considered a temporary hack. (Or a permanent hack, if you do all json decoding on the client.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the dataframe into json and pushed it, which worked